# How to crop the detected face

Tags: ios, crop, face-detection, core-image

I use `CoreImage` to detect the face. I want to crop the face after face detection. I use this snippet to detect face:

```
-(void)markFaces:(UIImageView *)facePicture{


CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imageView.image.CGImage];

CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                          context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];


NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];


CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, -imageView.bounds.size.height);


for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)
{
    // Get the face rect: Translate CoreImage coordinates to UIKit coordinates
    const CGRect faceRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.bounds, transform);


    faceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceRect];
    faceView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    faceView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(faceView.bounds.size);
    [faceView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Blur the UIImage with a CIFilter
    CIImage *imageToBlur = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:viewImage.CGImage];
    CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:imageToBlur forKey: @"inputImage"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 10] forKey: @"inputRadius"];
    CIImage *resultImage = [gaussianBlurFilter valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
    UIImage *endImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:resultImage];

    //Place the UIImage in a UIImageView
    UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    newView.image = endImage;
    [self.view addSubview:newView];

    CGFloat faceWidth = faceFeature.bounds.size.width;

    [imageView addSubview:faceView];

    // LEFT EYE
    if(faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition)
    {

        const CGPoint leftEyePos = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.leftEyePosition, transform);

        UIView *leftEyeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(leftEyePos.x - faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE*0.5f,
                                                                       leftEyePos.y - faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE*0.5f
                                                                       ,faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE,
                                                                       faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE)];

        NSLog(@"Left Eye X = %0.1f Y = %0.1f Width = %0.1f Height = %0.1f",leftEyePos.x - faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE*0.5f,
              leftEyePos.y - faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE*0.5f,faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE,
              faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE);

        leftEyeView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor magentaColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
        leftEyeView.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE*0.5;


        [imageView addSubview:leftEyeView];
    }


    // RIGHT EYE
    if(faceFeature.hasRightEyePosition)
    {

        const CGPoint rightEyePos = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.rightEyePosition, transform);


        UIView *rightEye = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rightEyePos.x - faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE*0.5,
                                                                    rightEyePos.y - faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE*0.5,
                                                                    faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE,
                                                                    faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE)];



        NSLog(@"Right Eye X = %0.1f Y = %0.1f Width = %0.1f Height = %0.1f",rightEyePos.x - faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE*0.5f,
              rightEyePos.y - faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE*0.5f,faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE,
              faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE);

        rightEye.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        rightEye.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*EYE_SIZE_RATE*0.5;
        [imageView addSubview:rightEye];
    }


    // MOUTH
    if(faceFeature.hasMouthPosition)
    {

        const CGPoint mouthPos = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.mouthPosition, transform);


        UIView* mouth = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(mouthPos.x - faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE*0.5,
                                                                 mouthPos.y - faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE*0.5,
                                                                 faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE,
                                                                 faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE)];

        NSLog(@"Mouth X = %0.1f Y = %0.1f Width = %0.1f Height = %0.1f",mouthPos.x - faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE*0.5f,
              mouthPos.y - faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE*0.5f,faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE,
              faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE);


        mouth.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
        mouth.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*MOUTH_SIZE_RATE*0.5;
        [imageView addSubview:mouth];

    }
}
}
```

What I want is just crop the face.

Comment: You posted some code that uses face detection to do something unrelated to what you want to do. That code DOES include calculating the rectangle for each face in the image in image coordinates. You next task is to adapt that code to extract and image at that rectangle into another image. You should be able to create a context that's the size of your desired output image and then use drawInRect to render the portion with your face into that image context. Try it, and if you have problems, post your code and ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily crop the face using this function.it is tested and working properly.

```
-(void)faceWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    CGRect rect = frame;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self.imageView.image CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *cropedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    self.cropedImg.image =cropedImage;
}
```

You just pass the face frame and the above function will give the crop face image.